# Flutter/Firestore - type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a horizontal list view inside a vertical list view using firestore as a data source. I have created a vertical list view and now need to create the horizontal. This is how my data is stored:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(80),
        child: MainAppBar(
          text: 'Pick an occasion...',
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('events')
            .orderBy('order')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: buildProductList,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget buildProductList(
    BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        DocumentSnapshot user = snapshot.data.documents[index];
        print(user.documentID);
        print(user.data['Occasions']);
        return Column(children: [
          ListTile(
              leading: Image(
                image: FirebaseImage(user.data['img_url']),
                height: 25,
                width: 25,
              ),
              // Access the fields as defined in FireStore
              title: Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.translationValues(-20, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: Text(user.documentID))),

          ListView(
            children: [
              user.data['Occasions']
            ],
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          )
        ]);
      },
    );
  } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
      !snapshot.hasData) {
    // Handle no data
    return Center(
      child: Text("No products found."),
    );
  } else {
    // Still loading
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}
```

Here is the error message I recieve:

```
I/flutter ( 9398): Birthday
I/flutter ( 9398): [18th, 21st]

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      buildProductList.<anonymous closure> (package:easy_tiger/screens/homepage.dart:53:24)
#1      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:448:22)
#2      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1136:67)
#3      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:140:29)
#4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1136:26)
#5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1149:55)
#6      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2620:19)
#7      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1142:11)
#8      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:356:23)
#9      RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1868:58)
#10     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:920:15)
#11     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1868:13)
#12     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:345:5)
#13     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:429:5)
#14     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:81:12)
#15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#16     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:11)
#17     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:377:11)
#18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#19     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:471:13)
#20     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1810:12)
#21     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1768:20)
#22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#23     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#25     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#29     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#31     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#33     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#41     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:173:11)
#42     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:495:7)
#43     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:242:7)
#44     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:401:14)
#45     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
#46     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:889:18)
#47     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:404:19)
#48     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:867:13)
#49     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:286:5)
#50     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
#51     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1056:9)
#52     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:972:5)
#56     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:253:10)
#57     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:211:3)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      buildProductList.<anonymous closure> (package:easy_tiger/screens/homepage.dart:53:24)
#1      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:448:22)
#2      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1136:67)
#3      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:140:29)
#4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1136:26)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Can someone help me solve this error? Here is the desired output:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: this is just a wrong assignment of a variable, for example assigning a string to an int, there are many question regarding the issue, console shows you where you are assigning the wrong variable, post the 53 line in your homepage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in ListView, you have to set the List of String as List of Widget. That's why you got this error.
Instead of using

```
ListView(
            children: [
              user.data['Occasions']
            ],
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          )
```

Use

```
ListView(
            children: [
              for(int i = 0; i< user.data['Occasions'].length; i++) Text(user.data['Occasions'][i]),
            ],
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          )
```